# user tabs customization

Tags: blocks

I have a site built with Drupal 7, and I allowed the authenticated users to see the other profiles. Till now, every thing was OK; the problem is when they click on the name of a user. They see the tab **"account"** by default, and I wanted them to get the tab "video" or blog entries instead.

I have the view, edit, video, account tabs, and I used the tab tamer in order to reorganize the theme, but the "Account" tab is still the default one.

How can I make the "Video" tab the default one? Where can I change it?

Please check [my site](http://www.elhannibal.com).

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any module that does this for you. So, you'll need to use a little bit of code to tweak things. What you need to do is implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) in a module to alter the way the tabs are organised. In particular, you will need to swap the menu *type* of the default tab and your video tab. The types in question are [MENU_LOCAL_TASK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_TASK/7) and [MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK/7); i.e., change the default tab to MENU_LOCAL_TASK and your video tab to MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK which should set the latter as the default. More information on these constants are provided on the [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) page.

Comment: sorry i don't know how to do and what to do ! any way thank you for replying.

Comment: If you know some rudimentary PHP, you can give creating a custom module a shot. See http://drupal.org/node/1074360 for more information. It is pretty easy for doing simple things :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [tab tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module to rename the tabs and also specify which tabs to show and which not to..it is also fairly simple to use ... hope it solves your problem.